# Wrap routes in a block in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following in Rails 3.2:

```
  # routes.rb
  resources :versions, only: :show
  post 'versions/:id/revert' => 'versions#revert', :as => 'revert_version'
```

I tried to wrap it to

```
  # routes.rb
  resources :versions, only: :show do
    post 'versions/:id/revert' => 'versions#revert', :as => 'revert_version'
  end
```

but it doesn't work. How should I wrap it in a block, or am I better off leaving it as it is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
resources :versions, only: [:show] do
   post :revert, on: :member, as: 'revert'
end
```

Comment: You can remove `as: 'revert'` block too.

Answer (score 1):

You COULD do this:

```
resources :versions, only: :show do
    post ':id/revert' => 'versions#revert', :as => 'revert_version'
end
```

You can then check your routes in the console with `rake routes`

However, there is no real advance to the first option.
For more information see the [Ruby on Rails Guides: Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/routing.html)